# Set up Flume HTTP agent on a URL?

Tags: hadoop, flume

I've been able to set up my HTTP source on a host and port like:

```
agent.sources=s1
...
agent.sources.s1.type=http
agent.sources.s1.bind=0.0.0.0
agent.sources.s1.port=5140
```

And I can, for example, POST a json document to it via:

> curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' -d '[{
>   "headers" : { "ip" : "192.168.1.102", "host" :
>   "random_host.example.com" }, "body" : "random_body" }, { "headers" : {
>   "ip" : "192.168.1.102", "host" : "random_host.example.com" }, "body" :
>   "really_random_body" }]' `http://hostname:port`

However I would like to be able to POST a Json document to `http://hostname.com:port/a/b/c/`

How may I do this?

Comment: I am searching for this answer as well. Did you manage to do it?

Comment: @Candroid Nope :( but keep me informed if you do.

Comment: I have decided to use `Apache httpd` service to proxy the sources running on the different ports

Comment: @Candroid Good idea. Do you see any downsides to using this, even if Flume provided what we are looking for out of the box?

Comment: Nope, for `http` source it should work just fine as we are using a service under the `apache` license. I am looking now for a way to send `POST` messages to multiple agents in a cluster (multiple sources bind to differed URL).I couldn't find Flume provided service so I was thinking about using WSD component. What are your thoughts about this issue?